# What is the interpretation of this liner?

Tags: meaning, paraphrasing, understanding

Source:http://blogs.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/mrsfunnybones/kohinoor-and-other-british-gems/

> But there is a silver lining to my eggplant-hued cloud. Now if trolls on Twitter badger me with the occasional ‘Go to Pakistan!’ I have a great comeback, ‘Oops sorry! Burnt my bridges there as well.’

What is meaning of this to an English reader?

> We eat a few more raspberry scones and switch over to discussing the great poet Rumi and Shams of Tabriz and **when I say that back home, we often refer to him as Shams Tabrizi, she retorts, ‘You Indians are obsessed with the British, want to rhyme everything with Angrezi — affected lot!’**

Only Bold part un-understood.Also whom they say 'affected lot'?

Comment: It's not easy to explain wordplay, puns, humor, and the like. But more importantly, I'm writing this comment because I can see four questions. Better split them four ways, IMHO.

Comment: There's too much going on this question - I agree with the previous comment, please consider splitting this into multiple questions

Comment: I think exactly.I will do , just give me a bit of time.

Comment: edited it a lot ,guys

Answer (score 1):

I will assume these are four separate questions.

1) The sentence could mean that she cannot go 'back to Pakistan' for she has committed a similar offence there as presumably she has committed here.

2) I suppose she is deriding your presumed Anglophilia and emphasising the point by rhyming Tabrizi with Angrezi.

3)This is a British colloquialism where the speaker is a little astonished that something quite clever has been said or done. As it is a colloquialism it escapes the long arm of grammar.

4) This statement is wrongly stated and can even seem vulgar when in fact all the writer is saying is to turn over the page. So it should be: For more information please see the next page.

Comment: whats 'But there is a silver lining to my eggplant-hued cloud'?

Comment: @Anubhav Singh. It means a dark cloud. Eggplants have  a dusky violet color. The writer is being a little poetical here changing slightly the conventional expression.